# Can GITKIT be used as a SAML idP?

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

I would like to connect SAML service providers (let's say Zendesk for example) to my "Google Identity Toolkit" users.

Is there a way (or any plan in the near future) to allow GITKIT to behave as a SAML identity provider?

Answer (score 1):

Google Identity Tookit does not support SAML provider or relying party yet. We do have thought of SAML integration but no concrete timeline in near future. You are more than welcome to post your request details to the [Google Identity Toolkit mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?place=forum/google-identity-toolkit#!forum/google-identity-toolkit).